# Index a view of a join query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, postgresql-performance

I have a `SELECT` statement that makes a very simple query from a more complicated view:

I have a fairly straight-forward select statement:

```sql
SELECT uid
FROM   userpermissions
WHERE  uid         = :whoami
AND    application = :application
AND    subsystem   = :subsystem
;
```

And my view is only ints and varchars, but a join of four tables (likely to be the real problem).

```sql
                       View "public.userpermissions"
   Column    |          Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Description
-------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 uid         | integer                |           | plain    |
 gid         | integer                |           | plain    |
 sid         | integer                |           | plain    |
 name        | character varying(128) |           | extended |
 application | character varying(128) |           | extended |
 subsystem   | character varying(128) |           | extended |
View definition:
 SELECT users.uid, groups.gid, groupaccess.sid, groups.name, subsystems.application, subsystems.subsystem
   FROM users
   JOIN groups ON groups.gid = users.gid
   JOIN groupaccess ON groups.gid = groupaccess.gid
   JOIN subsystems ON subsystems.sid = groupaccess.sid;
```

I'm unsure how to change the view so that my queries are more efficient, as they're taking about 1-4 seconds right now, and in some cases up to 8.

My other thought was to use a memcache, but that feels like a band-aid solution to the problem of an inefficient view.

Here's the output from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
                                                        QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=1.18..4.54 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.043..0.043 rows=0 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (groups.gid = users.gid)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.18..3.34 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.18..2.78 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.039..0.039 rows=0 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (groupaccess.sid = subsystems.sid)
               ->  Seq Scan on groupaccess  (cost=0.00..1.43 rows=43 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=1.17..1.17 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 0kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on subsystems  (cost=0.00..1.17 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Filter: (((application)::text = 'LoginLink'::text) AND ((subsystem)::text = '1'::text))
         ->  Index Scan using groups_pkey on groups  (cost=0.00..0.55 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)
               Index Cond: (gid = groupaccess.gid)
   ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..1.19 rows=1 width=8) (never executed)
         Filter: (uid = 2)
 Total runtime: 0.192 ms
(15 rows)
```

Which totally baffles me, because the moment I put it into PDO with PHP the query takes seconds, not fractions of a second.

Comment: how long it takes when you using pg_query? And, how far is your database server?

Comment: DB and Web are same machine. Command-line psql above indicates 0.192ms, when calling from PHP it indicates 3.6 *seconds*.

Comment: 0.192 ms it's the time in the database server, but if you use the function pg_query of PHP instance of PDO functions, how long does it take?

Comment: Using PDO, the query takes 0.09 seconds. I don't have pg_query in my code. Now I'm more confused... I don't think the query is my problem at all.

Comment: DB and Web are same machine, but are you calling the PHP script from another machine? The only thing I can think of is you may have a delay with the network.

Comment: SQL call with PHP and the database are the same instance. I need to investigate my issue further.

Comment: It's clear that the query has no problem and it runs very fast. Maybe you have a problem with the network or to blame for the slowness is in another part of your code.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect the queries are self-caching somewhere, this morning unchanged code took up to seven seconds, and now they're taking about half a second or less. I'm not familiar enough with PostGreSQL to understand where this takes place.

Comment: Even if the query was not cached, the cost is not enough (cost = 1.18 .. 4.54; Memory Usage: 0kB) to generate this time difference.

Comment: I agree, I'm simply unaware of caching and need to think over the issue more. Please cast a close-vote, the premise of my question is invalid.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A view does not help with performance. It is only good to simplify things, grant specific rights and some such. But it has no benefit for query performance.

You could try to cut out the middle-man (the view) and use this query:

```sql
SELECT u.uid
FROM   users u
JOIN   groupaccess g USING (gid)
JOIN   subsystems  s USING (sid)
WHERE  u.uid = :whoami
AND    s.application = :application
AND    s.subsystem   = :subsystem;
```

This also cuts out another middle-man, the table `groups`, which is not needed at all in your scenario. (Except if the connecting row for a user could be missing, which should not be possible.)

For performance, you would have to make that a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html), which is a different beast altogether.
Plus fitting indexes on individual underlying tables (and/or the materialized view).